# QEMU erro and permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu

I want to run mit's jos on my Ubuntu virtual machine, but I got some problems when I run "make qemu". Here is the result:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/gwaan/joslab# make 
+ as kern/entry.S
+ cc kern/entrypgdir.c
+ cc kern/init.c
+ cc kern/console.c
+ cc kern/monitor.c
+ cc kern/printf.c
+ cc kern/kdebug.c
+ cc lib/printfmt.c
+ cc lib/readline.c
+ cc lib/string.c
+ ld obj/kern/kernel
+ as boot/boot.S
+ cc -Os boot/main.c
+ ld boot/boot
boot block is 380 bytes (max 510)
+ mk obj/kern/kernel.img
root@ubuntu:/home/gwaan/joslab# make qemu
sed "s/localhost:1234/localhost:25000/" < .gdbrc.tmpl > .gdbrc
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local: Permission denied
'/usr/local' -hda obj/kern/kernel.img -serial mon:stdio -gdb tcp::25000  
make: execvp: /usr/local: Permission denied
make: *** [qemu] Error 127
```

I tried "chmod -R 777 /usr/local" but I still got "/usr/local: Permission denied"

QEMU was installed in "/usr/local"

gcc/g++ is the latest version

What I should do to run "make qemu" successfully?

Thank you in advance for any help. :)

Comment: The problem is that `/usr/local` is a directory, not a file and it's trying to run it. It sounds like you've set `QEMU` variable in `conf/env.mk` to a directory, and not to the qemu binary.

Comment: @Petesh I change `/usr/local`  to `/usr/local/bin/qemu-i386` and it works. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

When the file `conf/env.mk` was edited, the `QEMU` variable was set to a directory, not to the executable, so when it tried to run, you ended up with the error message:

```
make: execvp: /usr/local: Permission denied
```

This can be seen by the line, which is what make tried to invoke:

```
'/usr/local' -hda obj/kern/kernel.img -serial mon:stdio -gdb tcp::25000
```

To compile the module, you need to set the `QEMU` variable in the `conf/env.mk` file to the relevant qemu executable, and not to a directory.

When you ran make without setting the variable and there is no `qemu` in your path, you get the error message:

```
*** Error: Couldn't find a working QEMU executable.
*** Is the directory containing the qemu binary in your PATH
*** or have you tried setting the QEMU variable in conf/env.mk?
```